# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null (Error in Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, null, numberformatexception

I'm getting this error below. I'm retrieving my database from ***firebase*** and ***sqlite*** browser. Hoping that you guys could help me to sort this thing out.

Thank you in advance!

This is my **Database.java**:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME="coolblogDB.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;


    public Database(Context context) { super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER); }

    public List<Order> getCarts() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductId", "ProductName", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
        String sqlTable = "OrderDetail";

        qb.setTables(sqlTable);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

        final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                result.add(new Order(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
                ));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void addToCart(Order order)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice(),
                order.getDiscount());
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void cleanCart()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM OrderDetail");
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

This is my **logcat**:

> 10-15 13:48:34.439 12860-12860/com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2, PID: 12860
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2/com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2.Cart}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2.Cart.loadListDrink(Cart.java:128)
>                                                                                             at com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:71)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: print the stack trace

Comment: @RahulAgrawal i attached the logcat. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Cart.java line 128 like the following error says:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556) at com.example.mariamsyafiqah.coolblog2.Cart.loadListDrink(Cart.java:128) at

There is a line with something like this:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
```

Which will throw error if your stringValue is null or empty.  You need to do the checking if the string is a correct number or not first

Comment: This is my line 128:

total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));

Comment: You should check if `order.getPrice()` and `order.getQuantity(‌​)` return a valid integer value.

Comment: Dear sir, im sorry but im quite lost here. How can i check that my order.getPrice() and order.getQuantity() will return an integer value?